# How to change Filter Url in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, filter

How to change the URL of the Magento 2 store when *Filter* is applied. When I apply any *Filter* the `URL` looks like `https://jpm2.mydemoweblink.com/watches/alpina?jpf_gender=6780` where I want to change the `URL` to `https://jpm2.mydemoweblink.com/watches/alpina/jpf_gender/6780` just want to add **" / "** in place of **" ? "** and **" = "**... How can I sort this issue? Thanks

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-url-rewrite/ please visit this site and see if it helps

Comment: actually the issue is with filters else it works fine n in the above link they didnt set the link for Filters